# Uber API offers Uber Pool option + ability to send text message to drivers?

Tags: uber-api

Does the Uber API offered "Uber Pool" ride type when we requests price / time estimates? Also, when a ride is coming, do we have access to a phone number in order to text the driver?

This isn't so much of an API issue as it is a feature question / request that a lot of our users wanted. I contacted Uber's support team via email and they told me to post anything API related in StackOverflow...

Answer (score 2):

```
Does the Uber API offered "Uber Pool" ride type when we requests price / time estimates?
```

According to the [GET /v1/products](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-products) API endpoint documentation:

```
Some Products, such as experiments or promotions such as UberPOOL and UberFRESH, will not be returned by this endpoint.
```

Therefore, UberPOOL products are not avaliable through the Uber API.

```
Also, when a ride is coming, do we have access to a phone number in order to text the driver?
```

After you make a ride request using the [POST /v1/requests](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests) API endpoint the first state the ride will be in is the **processing** state, to which you'll receive a response similar to:

```
Status-Code: 202 OK

{
   "request_id": "852b8fdd-4369-4659-9628-e122662ad257",
   "status": "processing",
   "vehicle": null,
   "driver": null,
   "location": null,
   "eta": 5,
   "surge_multiplier": null
}
```

And as you can see you don't have access to any driver information in this state.

Then, as per the [life cycle of a request](https://developer.uber.com/docs/tutorials-rides-api#section-life-cycle-of-a-request), the request flow needs to move from the processing state to the **accepted** state, once a driver accepts your request.

The accepted state is the first state where you have access to driver details by either calling the [GET /v1/requests/current](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests-current) or [GET /v1/requests/{request_id}](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests-details) API endpoints.

You can know when the status changes either via a callback on your [webhook](https://developer.uber.com/docs/webhooks) or by [polling at a 3-5 seconds interval](https://developer.uber.com/docs/tutorials-rides-api#section-processing-a-request) one of the above Uber API endpoints to get the current status.

The HTTP response you receive after making one of the above HTTP requests looks something like this:

```
{
   "request_id":"852b8fdd-4369-4659-9628-e122662ad257",
   "status":"accepted",
   "location":{
      "latitude":37.7886532015,
      "longitude":-122.3961987534,
      "bearing":135
   },
   "pickup":{
      "latitude":37.7872486012,
      "longitude":-122.4026315287,
      "eta":5
   },
   "destination":{
      "latitude":37.7766874,
      "longitude":-122.394857,
      "eta":19
   },
   "driver": {
      "phone_number": "(555)555-5555",
      "rating": 5,
      "picture_url": "https:\/\/d1w2poirtb3as9.cloudfront.net\/img.jpeg",
      "name": "Bob"
   },
   "vehicle":{
      "make": "Bugatti",
      "model": "Veyron",
      "license_plate": "I<3Uber",
      "picture_url": "https:\/\/d1w2poirtb3as9.cloudfront.net\/car.jpeg"
   },
   "surge_multiplier":1.0,
   "eta": 5
}
```

At this point you have access to the driver's phone number which you can use to call or text.